# QField Freehand Digitizing Tool

Tags: digitizing, qfield

I saw the latest update of QField 1.8 wherein users are allowed to draw/digitize in freehand lines/polygons geometries.

I was wondering how can it be enabled in QField?

We badly need it in our fieldwork/geotagging activities of natural resources.

[image]

**I have finally found out how to enable it. It could be seen in the QField Settings. The "Consider mouse as a touchscreen device" should be disabled for the Freehand Digitizing function to work.**

Comment: You should post the answer to your question not inside the question, but post it as an answer and then accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of QField is 1.9.5 - you should really get this one,there are so many imporvements since 1.6

Here the url to the documentation of QField, it is pretty well explained:
https://qfield.org/docs/fieldwork/digitize.html#freehand-digitizing

Comment: Hi. I already checked the documentation and downloaded the recent QField app, but still, the Freehand Digitizing mode doesn't appear in my app. Is there a need to configure this first in QGIS? Thanks!

Comment: so the green "plus" sign for adding new features in the right bottom corner appears as soon you switchi nto digitizing mode?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't have the Freehand Digitizing button below the Topological Editing button as shown in the image. I was wondering if I have missed a particular configuration in QGIS that is needed for the Freehand Digitizing tool in QField to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Does your device have a stylus or pen? Freehand digitizing needs one of those (or a mouse) to function. The Freehand Digitizing button only appears if you approach the screen with a stylus.

Comment: Hi. Yes! I am using a Samsung Tab A 2019 with S Pen tablet. But whenever I take out the stylus, the Freehand Digitizing still won't appear. Is there a need to configure this first in QGIS; like a widget or something? Thanks

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing you need to set up in QGIS. I use QField for bird census. When selecting a line or polygone shape and switiching to digitize mode, the freehand button appears once I approach the tablet with the stylus to about 2 cm.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't want to make a new theme.

I have a problem, with freehand digitizing in Qfield. It works with connected mouse. When using stylus, I can activate the freehand editing button, but editing is only possible in traditional way by adding nodes.
The stylus I use is battery loaded, but without bluetooth or anything.

Tried on Samsung Galaxy S22 and Google Pixel 6 with qfield ver 2.8.5

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. If you have a question please open a new topic to ask it even if it is related to another questions.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/255755)