# QFIeld: Deactivating freehand button

Tags: qfield, digitizing, button

Is it possible to disable the `freehand digitizing mode` (button on the left top) in QField?

If so, how to disable this?

Comment: You can take a look at this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397594/qfield-freehand-digitizing-tool (see the last 2 sentences of the question)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have already read this. There it is described how the button is displayed although there is no pen. But my question is about this: Although I have a pen, the button should NOT be displayed. This can not be done in the setting described there.