QField freehand digitizing doesn't work
I am using an Oukitel rugged tablet for my fieldwork, which runs on Android, as well as the latest version of QField. I can activate the freehand digitizing feature in both my polygon and line layers, but every time I want to draw something I have to use the traditional node-adding system. I have tried my finger and an active stylus, but nothing seems to do the job. How can I freehand draw on my map? Does the layer need to be a certain type (i.e. multiline vs line, multipolygon vs polygon etc.)?

Did you try the hint from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397594/qfield-freehand-digitizing-tool ""Consider mouse as a touchscreen device" should be disabled for the Freehand Digitizing function to work"?

yes, I've tried everything on every forum. I can activate the function no problem, the freehand digitizing icon is on, meaning green, but when I try to draw the features I still have to add it point-by-point

possible open ticket https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/5010
